# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))'

Tags: vb.net

I've been working on a code in VB.net and this error happens when I try to launch :
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))'

Here is [The Quickwatch of the error][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsYPO.png

The error happens at line 10

```
With CostSheetApp.Workbooks(nameOfTheCostSheet)
```

And this is all the Sub

```
Private Sub CreateHoursAssignementsSheet(CostSheetApp As Excel.Application, nameOfTheCostSheet As String, Project As WBSProject, ByRef WBSResourceList As List(Of WBSResource), Optional withRiskString As String = "")
    'Variable preparation 
    Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_ST_RESOURCE = Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_FOLOWING_TYPE + 1
    Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_END_RESOURCE = Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_ST_RESOURCE + WBSResourceList.Count - 1
    Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_RISK = Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_END_RESOURCE + 1
    Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_MIN_HOURS = Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_RISK + 1
    Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_LIKEHOOD_HOURS = Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_MIN_HOURS + 1
    Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_MAX_HOURS = Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_LIKEHOOD_HOURS + 1

    With CostSheetApp.Workbooks(nameOfTheCostSheet)

        For Each sheet In .Sheets 'delete the old sheet if it exist

            If (sheet.name.Equals(Project.ProjectConstant.NAME_OF_COST_SHEET_SHEET + withRiskString)) Then
                Call .Sheets(Project.ProjectConstant.NAME_OF_COST_SHEET_SHEET + withRiskString).delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        'create the new sheet
        Call .Sheets.Add()
        .ActiveSheet.name = Project.ProjectConstant.NAME_OF_COST_SHEET_SHEET + withRiskString

    End With



    If (withRiskString.Equals("")) Then
        ExtractTemplateIntoCostSheet(CostSheetApp, WBSResourceList)
    Else
        ExtractTemplateIntoCostSheet(CostSheetApp, WBSResourceList, False)
    End If

    ' extend the range that are paste on all the rows necessary for the cost sheet
    With CostSheetApp.Workbooks(nameOfTheCostSheet).Sheets(Project.ProjectConstant.NAME_OF_COST_SHEET_SHEET + withRiskString)
        If (withRiskString.Equals("")) Then
            ' .Cells(Project.projectConstant.COST_SHEET_START_ROW + 1, Project.projectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_LIKEHOOD_HOURS).formula = Project.projectConstant.COST_SHEET_FORMULA_LIKEHOOD.Replace("0", CStr(Project.projectConstant.COST_SHEET_START_ROW + 1)) 'put the formula for the Likehood column to always display the max hours of all the line 

            .range(.Cells(Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_START_ROW + 1, Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_WP), .Cells(Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_START_ROW + 1, Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_MAX_HOURS)).Select
        Else
            .range(.Cells(Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_START_ROW + 1, Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_WP), .Cells(Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_START_ROW + 1, Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_END_RESOURCE)).Select
        End If
        CostSheetApp.Selection.Copy


        If (withRiskString.Equals("")) Then
            .range(.Cells(Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_START_ROW + 1, Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_WP), .Cells(Project.NumberOfTask + Project.NumberOfSumarryTasks + 4, Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_MAX_HOURS)).Select
        Else
            .range(.Cells(Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_START_ROW + 1, Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_WP), .Cells(Project.NumberOfTask + Project.NumberOfSumarryTasks + 4, Project.ProjectConstant.COST_SHEET_COL_END_RESOURCE)).Select
        End If

        CostSheetApp.Selection.PasteSpecial(Paste:=xlPasteFormats, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False)

    End With

End Sub
```

Hope that someone will be able to help me overcome this problem. Tell me if you need further explanation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems like there's no workbook with that name. You realise that you are using a sheet name to get a book, right?

Comment: the Workbook's name is Costsheet, so I'm trying to work with the variable nameOfTheCostsheet which refers to the name of the workbook but without extension like "Costsheet" instead of "Costsheet.xls"

Comment: Workbooks have Worksheets. Try getting the names of the worksheets to see what they look like.

Comment: @Mary I don't understand what you mean by to see what they look like, can you please explain further ?

Comment: To get sheet names... `dt = cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)` Where dt is a DataTable and cn is the connection that has been opened. Then `Dim exSheets = (From dRow In dt.AsEnumerable() Select dRow("TABLE_Name")).ToArray`

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I don't know how to use DataTables and connections in VB.Net, do I need to already have a DataTable defined and used or can I create a whole new one ? I don't get how it can get the sheet names, can you please again explain further ?